# Git: Bare or non-bare repository for WordPress in production

Tags: wordpress, git

I need guidance for how to managing file changes in my production WordPress environment in a typical Git setup (local, remote/prod)

In my workflow, I have a repository on my local machine (local) and a bare repository on my remote server (production). I am committing changes locally and pushing this to the bare repository. I then use a [Git post receive hook](https://gist.github.com/nichtich/5290675) to pull files to my production environment.

Challenge: In my scenario, WordPress is a stateful application; file changes happen within the remote, which needs to be tracked. For example, if a client installs a plugin, I need to be able commit these changes and keep them in sync with my local repository. In my current setup, changes in the remote (production) are not being tracked.

Should I therefore use a non-bare repository on my production server and use `git config --global receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead` to facilitate pushing from local to production. If so, what are the risks, or is there a better approach?

Comment: I would commit the changes in the productive instances repo and pull these to my local before changing something. I guess that anything else would cause data inconsistency.